# Delete repeated characters in strings in cell array

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array like this :

```
Input = {'CEEEGH';'CCEEG';'ABCDEFF';'BCFGG';'BCDEEG';'BEFFH';'AACEGH'}
```

How can I delete all of the repeated characters and just keep only 1 character left in each string in the Input ? The expected output should be like this:

```
Output = {'CEGH';'CEG';'ABCDEF';'BCFG';'BCDEG';'BEFH';'ACEGH'}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use :

```
cellfun(@unique,input,'UniformOutput',0)



ans = 

'CEGH'
'CEG'
'ABCDEF'
'BCFG'
'BCDEG'
'BEFH'
'ACEGH'
```

EDIT:

To conserve ordering in case the letters are not sorted, as @thewaywewalk commented, you can use:

```
cellfun(@(x) unique(x,'stable'),input,'UniformOutput',0)
```

Comment: Beat me to it, came up with exactly the same.

Comment: Best way to go, but I'd optionally consider the `'stable'` property of `unique` to keep the order in case the letters of the strings are not sorted.

Comment: @thewaywewalk How do you specify name-value pairs to function handles? I don't think I've seen it done before and the function handle documentation is pretty sparse.

Comment: @excaza just use `cellfun(@(x) unique(x,'stable'),input,'UniformOutput',0)` - directly in the handle is not possible, that's right.

Comment: @thewaywewalk darn, I was hoping for some new syntactic sugar :)